# Perform an Action when phone is shaked

Tags: java, android

I'm using [shake-detector-librart](https://github.com/safetysystemtechnology/android-shake-detector) to detect whether my phone is being shared or not. It is working fine, gives the exact results as needed in the background as well as while the application is opened. I need to perform any action when the phone is being shaken, but it isn't working for that. 
Here's my code:

```
 ShakeOptions options = new ShakeOptions()
            .background(true)
            .interval(1000)
            .shakeCount(2)
            .sensibility(3.0f);

    this.shakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(options);

    shakeDetector.start(this, new ShakeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onShake() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "locationDetails", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String msg_txt = "THis is a sammple sms";
            String phoneNo = "03036018110";

            System.out.println("jamoodgreat");
            //sendSMS(phoneNo,msg_txt);
            Log.d("event", "onShake");//this is not being printed
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Jamshaid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//this toast is not being displayed as well.

        }
    });



}
```

Comment: "It is working fine, gives the exact results as needed" What do you mean with this?

Comment: @HB. I meat to say that it works when I shake the phone, and as the result of the shake are required. It sums up the consecutive shakes as well. but the action isn't being performed as needed after shaking the device

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following and it works fine (The `Toast` gets called/displayed).

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ShakeDetector shakeDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ShakeOptions options = new ShakeOptions()
                .background(true)
                .interval(1000)
                .shakeCount(2)
                .sensibility(2.0f);

        shakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(options).start(this, new ShakeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onShake", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Even though it worked, I had to shake the device vigorously before it was picked up.